# How to schedule timing for a JOB in Postgres using pgagent

Tags: postgresql, jobs, job-scheduling, pgagent

I have created a job using pgagent which I have scheduled on every 5 mins for that below is the code:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    jid integer;
    scid integer;
BEGIN
-- Creating a new job
INSERT INTO pgagent.pga_job(
    jobjclid, jobname, jobdesc, jobhostagent, jobenabled
) VALUES (
    1::integer, 'refresh_mobile'::text, ''::text, ''::text, true
) RETURNING jobid INTO jid;

-- Steps
-- Inserting a step (jobid: NULL)
INSERT INTO pgagent.pga_jobstep (
    jstjobid, jstname, jstenabled, jstkind,
    jstconnstr, jstdbname, jstonerror,
    jstcode, jstdesc
) VALUES (
    jid, 'refresh_mobile_mv_data'::text, true, 's'::character(1),
    ''::text, 'ICSPGD'::name, 'f'::character(1),
    'SELECT refresh_materialized_views(''mobile'');'::text, 'Please check. Issue occired while refreshing Mobile Data'::text
) ;

-- Schedules
-- Inserting a schedule
INSERT INTO pgagent.pga_schedule(
    jscjobid, jscname, jscdesc, jscenabled,
    jscstart, jscend,    jscminutes, jschours, jscweekdays, jscmonthdays, jscmonths
) VALUES (
    jid, 'minutly'::text, ''::text, true,
    '2017-09-04 03:36:20-07'::timestamp with time zone, '2018-12-31 02:36:20-08'::timestamp with time zone,
    -- Minutes
    ARRAY[false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]::boolean[],
    -- Hours
    ARRAY[true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true]::boolean[],
    -- Week days
    ARRAY[true, true, true, true, true, true, true]::boolean[],
    -- Month days
    ARRAY[true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true]::boolean[],
    -- Months
    ARRAY[true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true]::boolean[]
) RETURNING jscid INTO scid;
END
$$;
```

But when I am checking its statistics(in pgadmin) or via query "select * from pgagent.pga_job;" it shows that job are running at an interval of 1 hour.

For example: If the last job run time is **2017-10-05 03:05:00.703287-07** , then the next run time it shows : **2017-10-05 04:05:00-07**.

Kindly help with the timing parameter. I am suppose to run this job on an interval of every 5 mins on a daily basis throughout.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
INSERT INTO pgagent.pga_schedule 
(jscid, jscjobid, jscname, jscdesc, jscminutes, jschours, jscweekdays, jscmonthdays, jscmonths, jscenabled, jscstart, jscend)
VALUES(<SchId>, 29, 'minutly', '', '{t,f,f,f,f,t,f,f,f,f,t,f,f,f,f,t,f,f,f,f,t,f,f,f,f,t,f,f,f,f,t,f,f,f,f,t,f,f,f,f,t,f,f,f,f,t,f,f,f,f,t,f,f,f,f,t,f,f,f,f}', '{f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f}', '{f,f,f,f,f,f,f}', '{f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f}', '{f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f}', true, '2017-10-07 00:00:00', NULL);
```

Basically, what this insert is doing is marking the minutes 0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50 and 55 for every hour.

I don't know why you're creating it using insert statements, since the GUI offers a pretty neat way to schedule jobs. The same configuration can be done using the GUI like this:

[image]

I hope it helps :-)